# Get Value out of Callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a callback, where I need to get the array out of my callback.

I am trying to return the awaited array into the predefined one.

```
let documents = [];

  socket.on('echo', async function(documents, data){
    documents = await data;
    console.log(documents); // shows me, what I want to see
  });

  console.log(documents); // empty Array
```

I need the result in my predefined Array `documents`

I have read several Tuts, but I dont get it. I know on stackoverflow it is sked several times. But all threads seem to be more complex then my situation. So I hope to get it cleared out with an more incomplex one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand something first. When this runs what is inside the callback doesn't run unit the server will emit that event, in your case 'echo'.

What I think you want to do is use documents outside the callback. You can create a function and call it when the event is emitted.

Something like this:

```
const manageDocuments = (documents) => {
    // do what you want with documents array
    console.log(documents);
}

socket.on('echo', async function(documents, data){
    documents = await data;
    manageDocuments(documents);
});
```

Of course you can also get rid of the async/await

Comment: nice one. bute How do i return it then? 

I have this hole in a function and I need to return it out of the function

```javascript
const manageDocuments = (documents) => {
    // I what to return these data
    return documents;
}
```
Can I do it like that? I tried, but when I `console.log(manageDocuments)` I cant see the data, I only see `manageDocuments()` as result.

I guess its because like @
Joaquín Romero Franco said

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Give me the exact code or try to explain a little bit better and I'll help you :)

Comment: I have done it this way :D

```javascript 
socket.on('echo', async function(documents, data){
    documents.push(data);
  });
```

I found out push works in callback :)

Answer (score 2):

```
let documents = await socket.on('echo', async function(documents, data){
    console.log(documents); 
    return data; 
  });

console.log(documents);
```

Comment: thy this one looks like a great idea :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code outside the socket function executes with the empty array because is only executed once at runtime.

If you want to have access to the documents inside the socket function you have to make then persist, or use the socket.on inside of another loop.